# Category names of chess pieces

Tags: american-english, programming

I am writing a chess computer program, and I call the Bishop a "Diagonal Piece", because it can attack diagonally and anti-diagonally.

How can I call the Rook which can attack vertically or horizontally?

I called it "Diametrical Piece" but I think it is very wrong.

Thanks,

Comment: say 'anti-vertically', and call it a vertical piece. or a ranking piece. or maybe an orthogonal piece. what have you called the queen/king?

Comment: There's also *rank-and-file* piece, because it moves along *ranks* and *files* on the board, but that could be misunderstood as *basic, foot-soldier,* which might be undesirable.

Comment: @Andrew Leach I like your suggestion, because" rank" and" file" are terms that are used by chess players, and so "a rank-and-file piece" would be understood by them. I have never seen a discussion about the rule for promotion of a pawn that did not talk about the pawn's reaching the 8th rank, and one ot the early things you learn in chess strategy is that rooks should "seize an open file."

Comment: It appears that "Chess-specific questions about programming a chess engine or other chess software are welcome" on [chess.se]. Given that this question is not particularly technical ("I call... what can I call...) I don't propose moving it over there, but a question might be drafted there about whether there are specific technical terms for these pieces. Whether you actually **need** special terms might be moot, because each piece can only move in a uniquely-defined manner. This community can come up with a general suggestion; that community may know specific terminology.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Oh wow, there's a "Chess" section for stackexchange as well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use *orthogonal,* which, while it means

> Of or involving right angles; at right angles.
>
> [[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/orthogonal)]

might not immediately indicate which directions a rook moves in (although those directions are at right angles), it may be a convenient contrast to *diagonal*.

You could also consider *perpendicular,* as the rook moves in lines which are perpendicular to the sides of the board.

> At an angle of 90° to a given line, plane, or surface or to the ground
>
> [[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/perpendicular)]

Answer (score -2):

The word you might be looking for is 'linear' meaning:

(from Dictionary.com)

```
adjective
1.
of, consisting of, or using lines:
linear design.
2.
pertaining to or represented by lines:
linear dimensions.
3.
extended or arranged in a line:
```

Comment: The bishop's path is equally linear.